# Jquery UI autocomplete with Ajax starts with

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am having problem with the autocomplete plugins of Jquery UI with Ajax.

It works locally but it does not always work in the server because the console gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null" whenever i use only one character or no character at all. it only works with 2 characters... its really weird really

These are my files

ajax.php:

```
 <?php
require_once 'config.php';
if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT id_pro, name, IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) as qty FROM inventory where ".$type." LIKE '%".$name."%' group by id_pro";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['id_pro'].'|'.$row['name'].'|'.$row['qty'];
        array_push($data, $name);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);exit; }?>
```

auto.js

```
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');

if(type =='id_pro')autoTypeNo=0;
if(type =='name')autoTypeNo=1;


$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[autoTypeNo],
                        value: code[autoTypeNo],
                        data : item
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");
        $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
        $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
        $('#stock_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
        $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);

        }               
});  });
```

despacho.php

```
   <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="id_pro" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt changesNo" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="name" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt changesNo" autocomplete="off" required></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="stock[]" id="stock_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="1" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a looooot of searching on the internet, i realize the problem. 
I was getting null values for all the fields with accent marks. the solution was simple

ajax.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SET NAMES utf8";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $query = "SELECT id_pro, name, IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) as qty FROM inventory where ".$type." LIKE '%".$name."%' group by id_pro";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['id_pro'].'|'.$row['name'].'|'.$row['qty'];
        array_push($data, $name);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);exit;
}
?>
```